# Siteminder active sessions limit

Tags: siteminder

Is it possible to limit the number of active user on a protected resources on a siteminder SPS? I want to assure that the protected resources is used by a limit number of active users let's say n.

Thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Session Limiting is available with SiteMinder as an add-on module by the vendor.  Please reach out to them, the maximum number of session for a given identity will be limited to the max that is setup in the authentication mechanism.  It will bump the oldest session to grant a new one - or it may even be configurable to not allow a new one, based on configuration.